# Good Coding Practice with Databases: One connection / query vs one connection / all queries

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

So I am finding myself struggling which is the best practice. This is my first time coding C# and first time coding anything in like a decade. Back when I worked as a php / sql programmer, we usually frowned on the idea of opening a new connection for every query, but the more I research this question on google today, specifically with C# and sqlite, the more it seems many recommend doing the polar opposite.

So, I was hoping the put this question out for some of you guys, who have obviously been doing this a lot more than eye. Here is the general setup of my database class:

```
class DatabaseController
{

    static private SQLiteConnection _sqlconn;
    static private string _uri;

    public static SQLiteConnection Sqlconn
    {
        get { return DatabaseController._sqlconn; }
        set { DatabaseController._sqlconn = value; }
    }

    public static string Uri
    {
        get { return DatabaseController._uri; }
        set { DatabaseController._uri = value; }
    }

}
```

The second class, which is the main Database class, which deals with actually running queries and such. The reason I have the DatabaseController class is because I can store the open connection handle to the static member _sqlconn and so the connection is only ever opened once, and Database objects simply use the same handle, even though the program can and will create many Database objects.

But again, is this actually necessary? Should I simply be opening a new connection within the main Database class, every time an object is created? There was another site and thread I found that apparently, what the .NET Framework does is even though you maintains a connection pool for you, so even though you might be opening and disposing of several connections, they aren't truly closed. Is this truly so, and does that apply to both desktop and windows 8 apps?

Comment: Opening and closing connections can be taxing on the system. IMO, most often I've seen a pooling system employed (you have several connections open at the same time and reuse them off from different threads (workers).

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to keep connections 'open' only for as long as they are needed i.e. as long as the unit of work requires.

As you have suggested, when you 'close' them they are not actually closed, but just returned to the pool for re-use by other threads/applications. This applies to any ADO.NET data provider.

If your application is single threaded, then you probably won't notice pooling occurring, but in situations when there are many threads requiring data-access then the quicker connections are returned to the pool then the quicker they can be re-used by other threads.

Answer (score 0):

When using sqlite you have to know how the engine was compiled. See here http://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html. It's important since sqlite behaves differently depending on the threading model used.

You might have to have logic where the connection is shared between all code that want to access the databse. You might also need code which prevents different threads from working with the Sqlite db simultaneously.

Most other ADO.NET providers supports connection pooling which means that the connections are reused when you invoke the `Close()` method.